# Descifrar Caligrafía Documento Registro Civil

Tags: historia, letras, parentesco, genealogía, orígenes

Necesito descrifrar las palabras marcadas para proseguir con mi árbol genealógico. Si me pueden ayudar se lo agradezco mucho. En la primera imágen el primer nombre puede ser Fabricio, Sabino o Patricio pero no lo sé con certeza. La segunda palabra es el nombre de una localidad asturiana creo que del concejo de Grado que viene precedido de San Juan (otra localidad) y ...  Y por último en la segunda imágen identifico Emilio Álvarez pero no logro entender el segundo apellido. Muchísimas gracias de nuevo al que quiera ayudarme. Un saludo

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que los nombres son Fabricio Álvarez, de San Juan y San Tirso.
De todos modos, creo que este no es el lugar adecuado para este tipo de preguntas. Hay en Facebook diversos grupos de Genealogía de cada región española, donde nos ayudamos unos a otros con este tipo de problemas. Por ejemplo, Genealogía en Asturias (https://www.facebook.com/groups/649128361901931)

Comment: De acuerdo, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Lo más probable es que sea:

-**Fabricio Álvares**

-**San Juan y ¿San Tirso?**

-**Emilio Álvares Grana**

Tengo muchas dudas con San Tirso porque pareciera que quiso escribirlo con tilde, cuando no lleva.

Comment: Comentario al margen de la respuesta: No es la mejor forma de escribir 'br'. Para los amantes de la cursiva, les recomiendo escribir 'br' haciendo una muesca al comeinzo de la 'r', [como se ve en esta imagen](https://imgur.com/a/rjK6Ugw)

Comment: Otra cosa: encontré [esta lista](https://fr.geneawiki.com/index.php?title=Lista-de-los-Pueblos-Asturias) para el que quiera seguir revisando si hay otro pueblo mejor para sugerir

Comment: Es posible que en vez de Gracia sea Grana pues por lo visto en la zona es común ese apellido. No entendía bien la primera letra. Gracias.

Comment: Es cierto, es más probable

Comment: @AlejandroFernándezCuesta ¿Por qué creés que es una 'z' lo que está al final de los apellidos?

Comment: Porque es el apellido de mi abuelo y sé que es una z aunque parezca una s

Comment: @AlejandroFernándezCuesta En ese caso la respuesta sería ya demasiado 'personalizada'. A fin de que sirva al resto de la comunidad debería estar basada solo en lo que aparece en la foto. Mejor la dejemos así.